# how can i get the email of the authenticated person?

Tags: twitter

At this point i just have an authenticated oAuth in php

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some more detail about your situation and your question.

Comment: I am using twiter_oauth class in PHP for the purpose of authentication via twitter. After authentication the user's name, screen_name are returned. similarly, is there any possibility of getting email address of the authenticated user?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. That information is not available via the Twitter API.